# Sublime Text: Pressing Esc from multiple selections -- put cursor at last selection?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

With Sublime Text, after a multi selection is with from CMD+D, I usually alter the text, then want to **escape the selections and have the cursor at where the last selection was**.

Some feature that are close:

- `CMD+U` will reselect selections
- `CMD+G` will skip to the next occurence
- `CMD+Shift+G` will skip backwards to the previous occurence

Are there any keyboard shortcuts that will do what I want, similar to Esc but forward, rather than backward?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a very simple plugin to do this, and then bind a key to it:

1. From the `Tools` menu, select `Developer` -> `New Plugin...`
2. Paste in the following:

   ```
   import sublime, sublime_plugin

   class SingleSelectionLastCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
       def run(self, edit):
           last = self.view.sel()[-1]
           self.view.sel().clear()
           self.view.sel().add(last)
           self.view.show(last)
   ```
3. Save it in the folder it recommends, name the file something like `single_selection_keep_last_cursor.py`
4. Open `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings - User`
5. Type/Paste in something similar to the following:

   ```
   { "keys": ["escape"], "command": "single_selection_last", "context":
       [
           { "key": "num_selections", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": 1 }
       ]
   }
   ```
6. Save it

This example creates a new plugin with a command called `single_selection_last`, and then binds the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to it when there is more than one selection. This therefore overrides the default <kbd>Esc</kbd> behavior of keeping the first selection.

The keybindings file needs to be a valid JSON array, so if it is empty you will need to wrap the example above in square brackets `[...]` for it to work.

If you wish to use a different key, you just need to replace `escape` with the key combination you want. See `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings - Default` for examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, save-me lots of problems. Here I created a package for this: https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeTextStudio/tree/develop/Clear%20Cursors-Carets